# Download file from ASP.NET Core api from Blazor client application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, client, blazor, webassembly

I created an ASP.NET Core api controller which return a `FileStreamResult` object. *(I can change the type of result if needed)*

Here is the code of the Get function:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{p_gInspectionID}/{p_nIndex}")]
public async Task<FileStreamResult> GetInspectionPictureToDownload(Guid p_gInspectionID, int p_nIndex)
{
  var l_strFilePath = await GetPictureFilePathAsync(p_gInspectionID, p_nIndex);

  using (var l_sReader = System.IO.File.OpenRead(l_strFilePath))
  {
    return (File(l_sReader, "image/jpeg"));
  }
}
```

Now I need to consume this result in the Blazor (Webassembly) client side application.

My goal is to have a button to launch the **download** of the file in the browser when user clicks on it.

This should launch download functionnality of the browser.
Is it possible to achieve this in Blazor client application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing, but my API was authorized, so after reading this [article](https://dev.to/j_sakamoto/implement-the-download-file-feature-on-a-blazor-webassembly-app-2f8p) I end up downloading the bytes in the web assembly application and use JavaScript to download the file from the bytes.

```
function downloadFromByteArray(options: { 
  byteArray: string, 
  fileName: string, 
  contentType: string
}): void {

  // Convert base64 string to numbers array.
  const numArray = atob(options.byteArray).split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0));

  // Convert numbers array to Uint8Array object.
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(numArray);

  // Wrap it by Blob object.
  const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: options.contentType });

  // Create "object URL" that is linked to the Blob object.
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  // Invoke download helper function that implemented in 
  // the earlier section of this article.
  downloadFromUrl({ url: url, fileName: options.fileName });

  // At last, release unused resources.
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this is the best solution, thank you for the proposal

Comment: Downloading huge files across the internet, always have downsides. Splitting chunks is also difficult with this approach.

Answer (score 5):

here is how I solved the problem. In fact the solution was really straightforward. Thank you @Data Juggler for pointing me in the right direction.

My Blazor solution holds two project:

- the server side API (Blazor server)
- the client side (Blazor WebAssembly).

Here is the code for the **server side**:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("[action]/{p_strPictureFilePath}")]
public IActionResult GetInspectionPicture(string p_strPictureFilePath)
{
  var l_sReader = System.IO.File.OpenRead(p_strPictureFilePath);

  return (File(l_sReader, "application/octet-stream", Path.GetFileName(p_strPictureFilePath)));
}
```

... and the code on the **client side**:

Added this script in `client-shared.js` file:

```
window.downloadInspectionPicture = function (p_strServerFilePath)
{
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = 'api/Data/GetInspectionPicture/' + this.encodeURIComponent(p_strServerFilePath);
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

*of course, a reference to that file is present in `index.html`:*

```
  <script src="client-shared.js"></script>
```

And finally, added a link in the razor file, and invoke script when link is clicked:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" @onclick="@(async () => await DownloadPictureAsync())">Download</a>

@code
{
  [Inject]
  IJSRuntime ThisJSRuntime { get; set; }

  private async Task DownloadPictureAsync()
  {
    await ThisJSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadInspectionPicture", ServerFilePath);
  }
}
```

Hope my answer is clear and can be useful to someone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if in fact your way is possible, but what I do is similar for my site https://pixeldatabase.net .

The user clicks the download button, and I show a link like this:

```
public async void Download()
{
    // Set the ImagePath
    DownloadLink = ImagePath;
}
```

[image]

Then on the page, I just show a Download link conditionallay:

```
@if  (HasDownloadLink)
{
    <a class="downloadlink" download="@FileName" href="@DownloadLink" 
target="_blank">Download</a>
}
```

Comment: Hello Data Juggler, thank you for your answer. What I want is to start directly the download process, without first download the file to local computer and then provide a link to that file. I think it is in fact what you do here. I mean, I want to use directly the FileStreamResult as source of the download functionality of the browser.

Comment: Are you still wanting the 'Save As' dialog box to appear for the user? The only thing I can think of is save the file and maybe some JavaScript way can click the button or start the download automatically.